Accidentally deleted the .encryptfs folder in the home directory
I recently noticed that the folder ".encryptfs" in the home directory was talking too much space so I deleted it. It was a bad decision as now all my files are lost.
Apparently this folder was created by the "encryptfs" utility. But I didn't try to encrypt my home directory with this tool and I didn't set any encryption password.
Is there any way to recover these files? Even if I could recover them, how can I decrypt them?
